# Proper syntax for specifying template parameters for a global templated operator?

Tags: c++

Sorry for the trivial question, but I could not Google this with a couple of attempts and decided to ask here. What is the proper way to specify the template parameters in this case:

```
#include <sstream>

struct bar
{
    int foo = 5;
};

template<size_t i>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, bar b)
{
    s << b.foo + i;
    return s;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::stringstream s;
    bar b;
    // Proper way of writing s << bar ?
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is that << operator supposed to be doing?

Comment: Assuming you *could* write `s << bar`, what value is the compiler supposed to use for `i`?

Comment: @NeilButterworth I know the sample is useless, it is just to show what I need. In real life I want to have the `size_t` value parameter to hold the size of string buffer that is needed to represent the string notation of a `sockaddr_in` / `sockaddr_in6` so that I can do `inet_ntop` in a templated operator for all address families.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are forced to use the long form to call the operator, and explicitly pass template parameters

```
int main()
{
    std::stringstream s;
    bar b;
    ::operator<<<1>(s, b);
    return 0;
}
```

### [Demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/RXD3EPsf3od7DRWd)

The `::operator<<<1>(s, b);` syntax looks weird, but focus on the `::operator<<` portion, which is referencing the operator in the global namespace. Since you've written it as a template, and the template parameter (`size_t`) cannot be inferred from the arguments, you are forced to use an explicit template parameter in the form of `<1>` (`<2>`, `<3>`, etc.)

Comment: Thanks:) I hoped there was a nice form, but oh well :D

Comment: In which case, using a named function rather than an operator probably makes more sense.

Comment: @NeilButterworth well, I still prefer chaining this with other `<<` calls instead of a named function, but thats a personal preference:)

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis:  There is no reason your `foo<1>(s, b)` can't return `s` by reference, and then you can write `foo<1>( s << "a", b ) << "c";`.  Though I would probably write that as `s<<"a"; foo<1>(s,b) << "c";`  You probably want a better name than `foo`.

Comment: @MartinBonner I know that I can do that:) As I said, I just wanted to know the syntax. After looking at it I actually had a `doh - why did I not just use a traits class` moment. But still good to know.

Answer (score 1):

Since your *function template* has no deducable argument, you will have to explicitly call it with the template argument. Its ugly.

```
operator << <4>(s, b);
```

Another ugly hack is to use a proxy *template-class*:

```
template<std::size_t K>
struct bT{
    bT(bar& bb) : b(bb) {} bar& b;
    static constexpr std::size_t i = K;
};
```

Then modify your template `operator <<` to:

```
template<size_t i>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, bT<i> b)
{
    s << b.b.foo + b.i;
    return s;
}
```

And call like:

```
s << bT<4>(b);
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0ab58129f235f9e4).. Anyhow we panel beat this, it still ends up being ugly. Save everyone the stress, and use a named function. That will be more legible an intuitive.

Comment: Thanks for the proxy idea, I'll keep that in mind if I ever need to to this again.